# How to globally swallow api error (findAll, query, adapter errors) in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way in Ember to globally swallow all api errors throughout the whole application rather than individually catching and reporting them in each component file?

Comment: Why would you want to do this??? If an api error occurs, you need to tell the user appropriately.

Comment: Yes, that is the intent but I want to handle it globally rather than handling at each individual file or component

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this, in your ApplicationAdapter, override handleResponse like this:

```
handleResponse() {
  let response = this._super(...arguments);
  if (response instanceof Error) {
    // return whatever;
  }
  return response;
}
```

For more about Ember Data Adapters, see https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/

You can find the default implementation of handleResponse here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.4.2/addon/adapters/rest.js#L894